# Is possible debug using breakpoints on a remote server without graphical interface?

Tags: php, debugging, breakpoints

How can I debug PHP codes on a remote server without graphical interface?

I will run the code on a browser. Can we insert breakpoints to debug the code, see the variables values, etc? Maybe using xdebug or zend_debugger?

If yes, how could I perform this? Please point tutorial to me.

Comment: the tools you suggest are a good option.

Comment: @Dagon - I assume you're following what's he's talking about, but for some reason I can't seem to figure it out (I'm also sick). What does "debug codes ... on a remove server with graphical interface" mean?

Comment: @JaredFarrish no not really, its clear as mud.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote — but debugging doesn't happen right in the browser, you have to hook it up to a client that supports the DBGp protocol which xdebug implements, e.g. notepad++ with its dbgp plugin. But other than that you can insert breakpoints and inspect variables remotely just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to breakpoints there are some other widely used methods to debug your PHP code on the server.

Wikipedia [defines it as print or trace debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques)

> Print (or tracing) debugging is the act of watching (live or recorded) trace statements, or print statements, that indicate the flow of execution of a process. This is sometimes called printf debugging, due to the use of the printf statement in C.

I like to call it [**Hi-driven development**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806572/558021)

> When you debug your program by writing alert('Hi') statements in a trial-and-error fashion

Basically the idea is that you setup your PHP code to echo or print out values at certain points in your code and then you can examine the output.  You can even utilize an `exit()` command after you print some value if you want the execution to halt there.

Another tip when using this method, especially if you are trying to debug a live server, is to wrap all the debugging statements in an IP address condition.  This way only **your** IP address will see these debugging outputs and other users won't notice anything different.

```
$ipWhiteList = array(
    '10.0.0.1', // office
    '10.0.0.2', // wireless
    ...
);
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$ipWhiteList)){
    echo "Debug  : I have reached this line of code!";
}
```